# Is OBIEE free? and what are system requirements?

Tags: oracle11g, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, obiee

Is Oracle Business Intelligence, v. 11.1.1.5.0 free to install? What are the system requirements for installing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [most recent price list](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/technology-price-list-070617.pdf), Oracle Business Intelligence Enterprise Edition Plus is $2000 per Named User or $300,000 per Processor at retail (though most people don't pay retail).  If your intended use falls under the terms of the OTN license, you should be able to download the software from the [Oracle Technology Network](http://otn.oracle.com) and install it.  But you'd have to determine whether the OTN license's terms were sufficient for you or whether you needed a proper license.

As for the system requirements, you'll want to review the documentation on the [installation scenarios](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/e10539/c2_scenarios.htm#CHDHFGEI) because it will depend on how many machines you are using and where all the components are being installed.  If you are asking about installing the entire stack on a single machine, it had better be a very powerful machine.  I couldn't imagine installing on a box with less than 4 GB of RAM and I'd want at least 8 GB before even thinking about it.

Comment: Is there any free edition avaliable for trail use?